# Storing arguments and function and using them in another function

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, stdtuple

Welcome, this is very rare use-case question.
So, here is what I'm trying to do - lets say I have a variadic template function which takes `T ...args` and a function type `FuncT funcName`, so here is what we have so far:

```cpp
template<typename FuncT, typename ...T>
void myFunction(FuncT (*funcName), T ...args);
```

Now, I want to store my function at `void (*)()` (this store functions). This works just fine.

```cpp
std::deque<void (*)()> functions;
func = functions.front();
func(std::forward<T>(args)...); //args is vardict template argument
```

Now, I can just pass a function to my function as in:

```cpp
template<typename FuncT, typename T>

int sharedArgument;

void setArg(int x){
  sharedArgument = x;
}
template<typename FuncT>
void myFunction(FuncT funcName){
  funcName(sharedArgument);
}

void function(int i){
  std::cout << i;
}

int main(){
  setArg(5);
  myFunction(function);
}
```

Now, **I know this is unnecesary**, but i want to present a more complicated problem that im having trouble with.

When i want to store arguemnts, I will probably use `std::tuple`, its design to store arguments, but 
**Main question is**: 
How do i store **variable amount** of arguments in tuple **and then** perfectly forward them as **normal arguments** to some function, so that function receiving

```cpp
function(std::tupleArgumentsHere...);
```

will read it as

```cpp
function(5, 42, "yes", 3.14);
```

I will use this to store arguments and pass them to `std::thread`.

Thank you, Cheers.

Comment: soo `std::bind`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply).  It is new in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17).  If you cannot, write your own.

In [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14), make an index sequence the same length as your tuple.  Then `func(std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tup>(tup))...)`.

In [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) do the same thing but write your own index sequence.

Comment: Tuple is variable length, thats the problem

Comment: @arma apply works with variable length tuples.  So long as you know the function type and the tuple type, just call apply with the actual correctly typed values.

Comment: Thanks, would be glad to know if there is c++11 way that works like apply, but still marking as the answear, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) stores the function and the arguments together. It returns a callable object encapsulating a copy of the argument values.

You can also use its "placeholder" facility in case there are additional arguments to add after calling `queue.front()`.